# "/showForm" does not redirect to the page showForm.jsp but "showForm" does it

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

index.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Home Page|Spring MVC </title>
</head>

<body>

<h2>Welcome to spring mvc</h2>

<a href = "/showForm">Form</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Below is my controller code

```
    @RequestMapping("/showForm")
    public String showForm() {
        return "showForm.jsp";
    }
```

Here is the **jsp code** I am using to render the showForm.jsp page, the problem is that whenever I am using   **/showForm** it gives **404**  and when I use **showForm** it render the **showForm.jsp** page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to return name of the `.jsp` page from the endpoint and also you have to append context path of the request with URI.

Modify to this :

index.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Home Page|Spring MVC </title>
</head>

<body>

<h2>Welcome to spring mvc</h2>

<a href = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/showForm">Form</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Controller :

```
@RequestMapping("/showForm")
public String showForm() {
    return "showForm";
}
```

It should work.

Comment: Thank you. It worked  but why it is not working by using " /showForm" and worked by using only "showForm" in the anchor tag. What is the logic behind ?

Comment: @shivamverma Why /showForm is not working because hyperlink needs an absolute link. It doesn't understand relative URL so for that you have to append context path.

Comment: @shivamverma Did you find ?

Comment: here is the link for the file that I am using 
I am following the spring course and new to the spring world

[link](https://easyupload.io/m/k7u6bc)

Comment: @shivamverma I saw the files. I don't see any issue.